# how to sum multiple calculations with one string

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, sum

[image]

I would need some universal string of commands, so I could insert it in cells A4, C4, D4, E4 and get those desired numbers across all the other similar cells like these.

So far I tried stuff like: `=IF(A1 = A2; SUM(A1 * A2); "1")` but still not close with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly do you want to do?

Not sure why you reference `A11` in your formula, or what you expect from `SUM(A1 * A2)` (do you want `A1+A2`? or `A1*A2`?)

Let's assume you want `A4 = 1` if `A1 = 1 or A2 = 1` and `A4 = 0` otherwise. Then type in `A4`:
    `=IF(OR(A1=1; A2=1); 1; 0)`
Then copy (or right-drag) `A4` and paste it in `C4`, `D4` and `E4`; the formula will adjust to these columns and work the same.

Please clarify your goal if you want better help :)

Comment: =IF(OR(A1=1; A2=1); 1; 0) - that is exactly what I needed, thanks a lot!! and sorry for that A11 typo up there